# How to remove double quotes from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var json = [
  "{"AccountType":"CurrentLiability","AccountCode":"880","Name":"Owner A Drawings"}", 
  "{"AccountType":"CurrentLiability","AccountCode":"881","Name":"Owner A Funds Introduced"}", 
  "{"AccountType":"TermLiability","AccountCode":"900","Name":"Loan"}", 
  "{"AccountType":"Equity","AccountCode":"960","Name":"Retained Earnings"}", 
  "{"AccountType":"Equity","AccountCode":"970","Name":"Owner A Share Capital"}"
]
```

I want in this format:-

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Array[62]
0
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:3216"
AccountCode
:
"090"
AccountType
:
"Bank"
Name
:
"Business Bank Account"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Edit the question so it reads less like a "give me the code" question.  Show us what you've tried.

Comment: ["{"AccountType":"CurrentLiability","AccountCode":"880","Name":"Owner A Drawings"}", "{"AccountType":"CurrentLiability","AccountCode":"970","Name":"Owner B Drawings"}"]

i want to remove the double quotes from first position and end position of object in array

Comment: Given JSON itself is not valid. How are you forming it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let objectArray = json.map((each)=>{return JSON.parse(each)});
console.log(objectArray) // This will give you the required output
```

Comment: json is not defined

Comment: json is your variable that contains the input Array.

Comment: @LalitRawat Just run the map function here on your input array, and each of the strings would be parsed into a json object, just like you need.